# Can I use HTC Vive to test my own developments?

Tags: htc-vive

My question is easy and short: I want to buy an HTC Vive to test my developments. I don't have a Development Kit.

If I buy it, can I use it to test my own developments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the development kits are free: native (C/C++) with OpenVR, or for Unity (many plugins) or Unreal or the many additional engines that are supporting the Vive.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure if I have understood your answer. So you say that I can use a commercial HTC Vive to test my owns developments, isn't't it? I'm not English speaker and I'm not sure if I have understood it. By the way, I'm developing my game VR using Unreal Engine.